# Retrieving the local timezone inside SQLite

Tags: sqlite, datetime, timezone, sqlite3

I have an SQLite table containing a "last changed" column with a date in the format e.g. "2022-11-07T11:51:06+01:00". Coreutils' date outputs this by using the following command:

```
date +%FT%T%:z
```

I can almost generate it from inside SQLite by using

```
SELECT STRFTIME('%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S', DATETIME('now', 'localtime'));
```

however, this lacks the timezone, and as far as I grasp the docs, there's no timezone placeholder.

So: Can I get the current local timezone using SQLite functions?

Comment: Shouldn't you let the user interface convert it to the localtime? Now it is just the locatime of where the database engine is located. Which maybe is different than the users?

Comment: It's not about conversion to display or process it. I wonder if I can get said formatted date and time from SQLite itself. It's only about the date and time where the database resides. Getting the local time is no problem. But when I store such a datetime and a DST change happens, the same hour exists two times when the time is shifted backwards, and such a timezone-less timestamp makes it impossible to figure out which hour it was.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot extract the timezone, but you can calculate it.

```
ROUND((JULIANDAY('now', 'localtime') - JULIANDAY('now')) * 24)   -- this gives the number of hours (signed)
ABS(ROUND((JULIANDAY('now', 'localtime') - JULIANDAY('now')) * 24 * 60) % 60)    -- this gives the number of minutes (unsigned)
```

The formulas above will give the difference in hours and minutes, of localtime from UTC. You can concatenate this info in your last changed column to add the timezone info.

```
SELECT STRFTIME('%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S', DATETIME('now', 'localtime')) || PRINTF('%+.2d:%.2d', ROUND((JULIANDAY('now', 'localtime') - JULIANDAY('now')) * 24), ABS(ROUND((JULIANDAY('now', 'localtime') - JULIANDAY('now')) * 24 * 60) % 60));
```

Comment: Actually, we need a ROUND() statement, because sometimes this yields 1.xxx and sometimes 0.9xxx, which will then result in "+00:00" instead of "+01:00". This works for my use-case but not for all timezones (we have some with fractional hours). I edited your answer accordingly. However: Thanks for this workaround! Apparently, this is simply missing in SQLite …

Comment: @Tobias Leupold yes, you are right. Fractional hours could be handled in the same way, calculating the minutes from the fractional part instead of adding a plain '00'.

Comment: Would you mind to edit your answer to be universally applicable?

Comment: @Tobias Leupold added minutes for fractional timezones.

Comment: Nice! Thanks a lot. This is for sure a hack, but it's a functional workaround for this (currently) lacking feature.